# how to prevent duplicates with inner join query (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I am trying to understand how to create a query to filter out some results based on an inner join.

Consider the following data:

```
formulation_batch
-----
id  project_id  name    
1   1           F1.1
2   1           F1.2
3   1           F1.3
4   1           F1.all

formulation_batch_component
-----
id  formulation_batch_id    component_id
1   1                       1
2   2                       2
3   3                       3
4   4                       1
5   4                       2
6   4                       3
7   4                       4
```

I would like to select all formulation_batch records with a project_id of 1, and has a formulation_batch_component with a component_id of 1 or 2. So I run the following query:

```
SELECT formulation_batch.* 
FROM formulation_batch 
INNER JOIN formulation_batch_component
ON formulation_batch.id = formulation_batch_component.formulation_batch_id
WHERE formulation_batch.project_id = 1 
    AND ((formulation_batch_component.component_id = 2 
        OR formulation_batch_component.component_id = 1 ))
```

However, this returns a duplicate entry:

```
1;"F1.1"
2;"F1.2"
4;"F1.all"
4;"F1.all"
```

Is there a way to modify this query so that I only get back the unique formulation_batch records which match the criteria?

EG:

```
1;"F1.1"
2;"F1.2"
4;"F1.all"
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way would be to use `distinct`:

```
SELECT distinct "formulation_batch".* 
FROM "formulation_batch" 
INNER JOIN "formulation_batch_component" 
ON "formulation_batch"."id" = "formulation_batch_component"."formulationBatch_id" 
WHERE "formulation_batch"."project_id" = 1 
    AND (("formulation_batch_component"."component_id" = 2 
        OR "formulation_batch_component"."component_id" = 1 ))
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about distinct. Its not the greatest performance wise, but still better than filtering it out at the software level.

Answer (score 27):

In this case it is possible to apply the `distinct` before the `join` possibly making it more performant:

```
select fb.* 
from
    formulation_batch fb
    inner join
    (
        select distinct formulationbatch_id
        from formulation_batch_component
        where component_id in (1, 2)
    ) fbc on fb.id = fbc.formulationbatch_id 
where fb.project_id = 1
```

Notice how to use alias for the table names to make the query clearer. Also then `in` operator is very handy. The use of double quotes with those identifiers is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the idea on the optimization. The query is actually being generated by an ORM, but I think I have a way to implement it like this instead (in much the same way I modified it to select distinct on the outer query).

Comment: In my tests, innerjoining like above was also faster than using the formulationbatch_ids in a where clause, ie:
`select fb.* 
from
    formulation_batch fb
where fb.project_id = 1 AND fb.id IN (
        select formulationbatch_id
        from formulation_batch_component
        where component_id in (1, 2)
    )`

Answer (score 2):

I know the question asks how to prevent duplicates with inner join but could use an IN clause in the predicate.

```
SELECT "formulation_batch".* 
FROM "formulation_batch" fb
ON "formulation_batch"."id" = "formulation_batch_component"."formulationBatch_id" 
WHERE "formulation_batch"."project_id" = 1 
 AND fb.id IN (SELECT "formulation_batch"."id"
               FROM formulation_batch_component
               WHERE (("formulation_batch_component"."component_id" = 2 
                      OR "formulation_batch_component"."component_id" = 1 ))
```

Comment: This is the best solution to the question I was trying to ask. Cheers!

Comment: I tested both this and @Clodoaldo Neto's answer, inner joining was ~50% faster in my case